# Elasticsearch getting http request performance

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 10 ES Servers each one with 32Cores Cpu, 256G memory and 10Gb NIC. The ES cluster will face about 9000 times request(index or query) per second. Do you think this would be a problem, or any optimization I should do please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the index structure, data amount and the queries you're doing. Hardware alone does not guarantee anything. I have seen clusters two times less powerful than yours which were capable to handle 10k/sec. However I can easily imagine queries and aggregations that will take some time to run on your cluster.